# Why square a constant when determining variance of a random variable?

Tags: probability, means, constants, variance

If I want to calculate the sample variance such as below:

[image]

Which becomes: $\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^2 \cdot n(\sigma^2)= \frac{\sigma^2}{n} $...

My question is ***WHY*** does it become $$\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^2?$$
In other words, why does the $(1/n)$ inside the variance become $(1/n)^2$?

I've read that this is because:

> When a random variable is multiplied by a constant, it's variance gets multiplied by the square of the constant.

Again, though, I want to know ***why***?

I've looked in multiple sources but they all seem to gloss over this point. I want to visually see *why* this is done.

Could someone please demonstrate why the $1/n$ is squared using my example?

---

**Update**:

As @symplectomorphic points out in a [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1708266/why-square-a-constant-when-determining-variance-of-a-random-variable#comment3486384_1708286) under [their answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1708286/258997), my confusion was the result of not realizing there was a difference between the **variance of a *set of data*** and the **variance of a *random variable***.

- See @symplectomorphic's other [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1708266/why-square-a-constant-when-determining-variance-of-a-random-variable#comment3486382_1708286) for an explanation of the difference.

@symplectomorphic's [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1708286/258997) provides a good conceptual walkthrough, while user @Tryss's [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1708274/258997) provides the correct mathematical explanation. Thanks to both of you!

Comment: The variance is a quadratic function. Just look at any of its definitions.

Comment: Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=22-BosVytkE

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You have that

$$\text{Var}(aX) = E[(aX)^2]-(E[aX])^2 = E[a^2 X^2]-(aE[X])^2 $$

$$=a^2 E[ X^2]-a^2(E[X])^2 $$
$$= a^2( E[X^2]-(E[X])^2 ) = a^2 \text{Var}(X)$$

edit : or this one may be more basic (depending on your definition of variance)

$$\text{Var}(aX) = E[(aX-E[aX])^2 ] = E[(aX-aE[X])^2 ]  $$

$$=E[a^2(X-E[X])^2 ] $$
$$= a^2E[(X-E[X])^2 ] = a^2 \text{Var}(X)$$

Comment: I don't follow. Could you put it into the context of my equation above?

Comment: @theforestecologist : use my post with $a=1/n$ and $X = X_1+ \cdots + X_n$

Comment: Your edit makes more sense to me.

Comment: @theforestecologist : no, my $X$ is $X_1 + \cdots + X_n$

Comment: Sorry just saw that :p

Comment: So then back to my example...based on what you're showing, my example pulled the 1/n out from the Var() too soon to make logical sense (and was just anticipating the ability to move it out and square it)?

Comment: @theforestecologist : no, your exemple makes perfect sense... I don't see what you don't understand. Let's note $Y = X_1+\cdots+X_n$, then $Var(\bar{X}) = Var(\frac{1}{n} Y) = \frac{1}{n^2} Var(Y) = \frac{1}{n^2} Var(X_1+\cdots+X_n)$

Answer (score 15):

Tryss's answer is correct. But you seem to need a more elementary illustration. Here it is, at least for the variance of sample data. (Your question is really about the variance of a random variable, but the point is the same.)

Take the two numbers $1$ and $3$. The mean of this set of data is 2. The variance is the average squared deviation from the mean. The deviations from the mean are $-1$ and $1$, so the squared deviations are $1$ and $1$, so the average squared deviation is $1$. Hence the variance of this set of data is 1.

Now look what happens when we multiply the dataset by 4. Our two numbers become 4 and 12. The mean is now 8. (This illustrates that when you multiply by a constant, the mean gets multiplied by that constant.) The deviations from the mean are $-4$ and $4$ (the deviations also get multiplied by the constant). Therefore the *squared* deviations are 16 and 16, so the averaged squared deviation is $16$. Hence the variance of this new set of data is 16.

Moral: when we multiplied our data by 4, the variance got multiplied by 16. This is totally unsurprising, because the variance is the average *squared* deviation. When you multiply your data by a constant, the deviations also get multiplied by that constant, so the *squared* deviations get multiplied by the *square* of that constant.

Comment: Ok the two of you helped me out. I get it now. My problem was that I always thought that Var = $\Sigma(x_i - X)^2 / n$ and not simply $(x_i - X)^2$. I guess the fomer would be called "population variance" and the latter is just ..."variance"?

Comment: though your answer helped me realize this important issue, I'm going to accept Tryss's answer b/c it should be more helpful for other people later on. Please don't remove yours though!

Comment: @theforestecologist: evidently you are still confused because your first comment makes no sense. the variance of a set of data *is* defined as $(1/n)\Sigma_{i=1}^n(x_i-\mu)^2$ (or possibly $1/(n-1)$ depending on how pedantic you want to be, but this makes no difference when $n$ is huge). I used this formula implicitly in my post: it just says to take the average of the squared deviations from the mean. (the variance of a random variable $X$ is different, defined in terms of expectations: $\text{Var}(X)=E[(X-E[X])^2]=E[X^2]-E[X]^2$.)

Comment: perhaps you are confused because you don't understand the difference between the variance of a set of data and the variance of a random variable.